# Compare 2 rows from sql table to get the avg distance

Tags: sql

I have a table which saves the latitude and longitude for a user . I want to calculate the avg  distance traveled by the user.
My table looks like :

```
UserId   Latitude         Longitude
   4      29.682127 -66.241321
   4      56.682127 -88.241321
   4      89.682127 -66.241321
   5      55.683114 -44.241102
   4      88.683114 -33.241102
   4      23.682127 -33.241321
```

I have a function which calculates the distance from two lat and long values.

Thanks
Abhinav

Comment: Do you have a timestamp column, or any other column that can be used to determine the order of events?

Comment: Yeah order is required. Distnace will depend on it. Second: Do You mean Full distance? Or Average distance?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can easily be done using window functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to sort the rows of the table, by adding a column "Id" which increments for each row:

```
Id UserId   Latitude  Longitude
1   4      29.682127 -66.241321
2   4      56.682127 -88.241321
3   4      89.682127 -66.241321
4   5      55.683114 -44.241102
5   4      88.683114 -33.241102
6   4      23.682127 -33.241321
```

Then, you can do this:

```
SELECT t1.UserId
     , t1.Latitude AS "LatFrom", t1.Longitude AS "LongFrom" 
     , t2.Latitude AS "LatTo", t2.Longitude AS "LongTo" 
FROM YourTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable t2 ON t2.UserId=t1.UserId AND t2.Id > t1.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable t3 ON t3.UserId=t1.UserId AND t3.Id > t1.Id AND t3.Id<t2.Id
WHERE t2.Id IS NOT NULL 
  AND t3.Id IS NULL
```